# Weshalb schreibt man "löst" nicht mit >ß<?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

Es heißt

> Du löst die Aufgabe.

nicht

> Du lößt die Aufgabe.

oder

> Du löhst die Aufgabe.

Da man `löst` nicht als `lösst` spricht, frage ich mich, weshalb es nicht `lößt` oder `löhst` heißt.

- Hat es etwas damit zu tun, dass `löst` von `lösen` kommt?
- Hat es etwas damit zu tun, dass man `hören`auch nicht wie `hörren`spricht, aber dennoch nicht `höhren`schreibt? (vgl. `lösen` nicht `löhsen`)
- (Weshalb schreibt man dann aber `Ahnung` bzw. `ähnlich`?)

Comment: Interessant dazu wäre, warum essen zu "du aßt" wirst.

Comment: Offenbar, weil es sich seit dem 8. Jahrhundert so bewährt hat, siehe [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/l%C3%B6sen), Abschnitt Etymologie.

Comment: @guidot Ich finde es spannend, dass es bei "dehnen" anscheinend nicht so war/ist. https://www.dwds.de/wb/dehnen#etymwb-1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Schreibweise *löst* folgt dem Grundsatz, dass eine Verhärtung von Auslauten am Silbenende oder vor anderen Konsonanten in der Schreibung nicht berücksichtigt wird (§23 der amtlichen Regeln).

D.h. die Schreibung orientiert sich im Fall von *löst* an Wörtern wie *lösen*, wo das s am Silbenanfang steht und daher stimmhaft ist. Eine Verhärtung zum stimmlosen s vor t bleibt unberücksichtigt.

*Essen* / *aßt* ist übrigens keine Ausnahme von dieser Regel, da das s in "Essen" schon stimmlos ist, was durch die Verdoppelung angezeigt wird. Der Wechsel von ss zu ß resultiert daraus, dass in *aßt* das a lang ausgesprochen wird.

Dafür, das es nicht *löhsen* / *löhst* heißt, lässt sich nicht so einfach ein Grund angeben. Das Dehnungs-h ist zwar überflüssig (lösen und *löhsen werden gleich ausgesprochen), aber es gibt etliche Wörter, in denen ein eigentlich überflüssiges Dehnungs-h vorhanden ist (vgl. denen/dehnen). Ein Grund könnte sein, dass vor s fast nie ein Dehnungs-h steht.